# how to relocate svn to new url?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, svn, tortoisesvn

I have a changed repository server to new url.Now i want to relocate my svn  working copy to new one.

I have found various links but not solution for my problem with 
    apache2.4, svn 1.8 and ubantu 14.0

When i m using following command its generating a error:

```
svn switch --relocate old_repo_url new_repo_url

svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 


svn: E175002: OPTIONS request on 'repository name' failed: 408
Request Time-out
```

Why this error i m facing even repository is exist and even same link is open on browser.

Could any one there to suggest the solution or why m not able to relocate.

Comment: *When i m using following command* - which one? Command is missing in question.

Comment: @Ivan i have added command..for this i was trying to relocate my svn working copy..

Comment: Have you tried to do anything else with *new_repo_url*, such as fresh `checkout`, to make sure your *new_repo_url* works fine? I doubt this has to do anything with `svn switch`. Btw, paramter is `--relocate`, not `--relocation`: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html

Comment: @Ivan .sry relocation is typo mistake... i have also tried to checkout but same error is there.But i have open same url in browser its listing all the existing folders(means its open with browser.)